# Why does using CGI::escape for my link URL make my browser take me to the wrong place?

Tags: perl, cgi, url-encoding

I am using the CGI escape method to escape the url for the href link tag.
Without the escape() call the link works fine in my browser because it is smart enough to translate the spaces as part of the URL.

My cgi script has this

```
print $outhtml->a({href=>$outhtml->escape($wavURL)}, $outhtml->escapeHTML($exportFilename));
```

where `$outhtml` is a CGI object and wav URL is `http://localhost/downloads/My File.mp3`

With the escape, the output is:

```
<a href="http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdownloads%2FMy%20File.mp3">My File</a>
```

This looks okay to me, but chrome treats this as a relative link, so when I click on it or copy the link address, it appends localhost/cgi-bin, giving a malformed address like so:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdownloads%2FMy%20File.mp3
```

I've tried this without the leading `'http://'` in the raw URL as well, and it produces the same bad behavior.  I also tried using an absolute URL without the hostname, like `/downloads/My File.mp3`, but this also has the same behavior.  I've tested this on chrome and firefox and both have the same result.

I also tried URI::Escape, but it did the same thing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should escape only values of CGI parameters but not the whole URL. For instance:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/get_file_by_url.pl?where=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdownloads%2FMy%20File.mp3
```

The value of `where` has to be escaped. The [URI](http://p3rl.org/URI) module helps you.

```
use URI;
my $myurl = URI->new('http://localhost/downloads/My File.mp3');
print $myurl->as_string, "\n";
# http://localhost/downloads/My%20File.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just escape the file name.

Comment: I tried it and this works.  But I am still looking for why escaping the beginning of the URL isn't working.  As I said, not escaping anything also works for me (although it would supposedly break for older browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Because `escape` converts any character that has special meaning in a URL so it can be used as data. If you feed in a complete URL then you get things like  `//` (which separates the scheme from the host) being converted to `%2F%2F` (two slash characters).

Answer (score 0):

A VERY old question, but no actual true answer.

As you pointed out, not escaping anything would supposedly break for older browsers.  Escaping **some** of the URL doesn't break older browsers because the browser (old and new) is taking the link as-is.

It first looks for the URL to start with "(protocol):" and if not found, defaults to 'http:'.  Then it looks for //servername/, and if not found, defaults the server the current page is on.  The match for ':' and '//' is literal, the browser does not unescape the URL for this.

In fact, unescaping of the URL does not happen until it reaches the program that will process the URL.  If URL is for a CGI program, that CGI program will receive the entire escaped URL and it's up to the CGI program to unescape it.

But for it to reach that point, the protocol, server name, and CGI program, along with the special characters, must not be escaped.
Escaping is not